# Why do I get repeated dates in forecast arima in R?

Tags: r, date, arima, forecast

I have a question about date format in forecast in R. Suppose I have a daily data:

```
library(forecast)
data <- c(10,20,15,10,5,20,5,10,23,6,9,9,4,6,3)
data_ts <- ts(data, start = c(2019,1), end = c(2019,15),frequency = 365)
```

And I estimate a model with *auto.arima* and do the forecast:

```
model <- auto.arima(data_ts)
forecast(model,h=10)

          Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95
2019.0411       10.33333 2.218446 18.44822 -2.077316 22.74398
2019.0438       10.33333 2.218446 18.44822 -2.077316 22.74398
2019.0466       10.33333 2.218446 18.44822 -2.077316 22.74398
2019.0493       10.33333 2.218446 18.44822 -2.077316 22.74398
2019.0521       10.33333 2.218446 18.44822 -2.077316 22.74398
2019.0548       10.33333 2.218446 18.44822 -2.077316 22.74398
2019.0575       10.33333 2.218446 18.44822 -2.077316 22.74398
2019.0603       10.33333 2.218446 18.44822 -2.077316 22.74398
2019.0630       10.33333 2.218446 18.44822 -2.077316 22.74398
2019.0658       10.33333 2.218446 18.44822 -2.077316 22.74398
```

Now see what happens if I transform the dates in the format *%Y-%m-%d*:

```
format(date_decimal(as.numeric(row.names(as.data.frame(forecast(model,h=10))))),"%Y-%m-%d")

"2019-01-16" "2019-01-16" "2019-01-18" "2019-01-18" "2019-01-20" "2019-01-21" "2019-01-21"
"2019-01-23" "2019-01-23" "2019-01-25"
```

I get repeated days. My question is: it is correct? I have to interpret it as they are the same day? Or may be these dates are incorrect and I have to consider each point as they are different days?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert the `forecast` object into a `data frame` and then extract the `rownames`. 
You can do as follows:

```
as.Date(time(forecast(model, h=10)), origin = "2019-01-15")
```

Make use of `as.Date` and `time` functions and supply the appropriate `origin` date and you will get:

```
"2019-01-16" "2019-01-17" "2019-01-18" "2019-01-19" "2019-01-20" "2019-01-21" "2019-01-22" "2019-01-23" "2019-01-24"
"2019-01-25"
```

Hope this is what you expect.